# Windows 10 "Add a VPN connection" stuck on save

Tags: vpn, pptp, windows-10

Since updating to Windows 10, we haven't been able to connect using our VPN anymore.

Every time we try to add it using the new interface it stays stuck on save.
The old interface just directs us to the new one.

[image: screenshot (removed IP)]

As you can see from the screenshot, the save turns gray and just stays that way.

The VPN uses PPTP (MS-CHAPv2) and is working fine on older versions of Windows, Android and Linux.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or an alternative client we could use?

Comment: You need to put something in the server name or address field, such as the ip address or public DNS name of the VPN server.

Comment: @joeqwerty I did, i just blanked out the IP address to post here.

Comment: Did you fix this? Same issue here

Comment: @Riccardo Yes for us this problem was due to a setting in Mcafee to block password stealers. By turning off that setting, we were able to save the connection.

Comment: I have  fixed the problem resetting the network. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the VPN using Powershell:

Add-VpnConnection -Name "Work VPN" -ServerAddress "8.8.8.8" -TunnelType Pptp -EncryptionLevel Required -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -SplitTunneling  -RememberCredential -PassThru

This returned "The system could not update the phone book file".
That's how i stumbled on the solution, a recently updated Mcafee rule "Protect phonebook files from password and email address stealers" was preventing me from adding new VPN connections.

Comment: Yep, this was my problem too.  The McAfee Access Protection log file confirmed the same symptom, and turning off Access Protection allows it to be saved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on a vanilla win 10 instance then add your custom software 1 by 1.  I've seen AV, insecure UAC settings, malware etc. cause this behavior.